# SwipeRefreshLayout Scrolling Issues with AppBarLayout Overlap or Overlay

Tags: java, android, mobile, kotlin

I have set up a AppBarLayout with a SwipeRefreshLayout and all works great except when I add app:behavior_overlapTop="200dp" to the layout. I am able to swipe down to refresh everywhere except for where the SwipeRefreshLayout overlaps the AppBarLayout. [Image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNJrb.png). The yellow in the image indicates the area where I can't swipe down on. Here is my code for reference.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_header"
        android:background="@color/red"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/red"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:src="@drawable/cp_logo_stack" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_header_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/red"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/updated_home_page_reload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="@string/permissions_failure_page_text"
            android:textColor="@color/detailsBorderColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_page_try_again_button"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@color/detailsBorderColor"
            android:text="@string/permissions_try_again"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_page_pull_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="140dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/te"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">


        <GridView
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:columnWidth="165dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="15dp" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I tried used the setOverlayTop and got the same results.